# ListView does not update if underlying data is being updated by the ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

The issue I'm having is this:  I have  WPF ListView that is bound to an ObservableCollection of objects that implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  In the setters for my properties I do some data validation and in the case where the user enters invalid data I will pop up a message box and set the property to a default value.  This is currently all working.  The issue is that if the property is being updated through user input in the ListView, if the user enters "invalid" data while the property does get updated to the default value the ListView is not updating to reflect that

For example, given the code below, if the user were to enter the letter 'a' for the Device ID column, they will get a pop up, and the property will be set to -1 but the ListView will continue to show 'a'.

XAML for ListView:

```
<ListView Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="configListView" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=''}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="EditItemGotFocusDelegate"/>
         </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Device ID" Width="75">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DeviceID}" Margin="-6,0,-6,0"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <!-- More Columns declared just like above -->

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Code for property is as follows:

```
class ConfigItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _DeviceID = -1;
    /* More variables...*/

    /* Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged */
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }

    /* Property definition */
    public string DeviceID
    {
        get
        {
            if (_DeviceID == -1)
            {
                return "<Default>";
            }
            else
            {
                return _DeviceID.ToString();
            }
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == "")
            {
                _DeviceID = -1;
            }
            else if(int.TryParse(value, out _DeviceID) == false || _DeviceID > 1023 || _DeviceID < 0)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Device ID must be a number greater than 0 and less than 1024");
                _DeviceID = -1;
            }
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DeviceID");
        }
    }

    /* More Properties definitions exactly as above */
}
```

Comment: It all looks pretty ok at first sight. What happens when you call NotifyPropertyChanged with null? This must refresh the complete object instance. And put a breakpoint at the getter and see if it gets called at certain points. PageLoad, editing the property etc.

Comment: I recommend you check out the IDataErrorInfo interface and how to use this for WPF Data Validation. Here is a good tutorial: http://tarundotnet.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-idataerrorinfo-in-wpf/

Comment: What version of .NET?  I had this problem with a simple TextBox.  Going to .NET 4.5 fixed it.  But I am currently having the problem with ComboBox SelectedIndex.   It is like the UI element decides it knows better and ignores the get.

Comment: The getter is being called at page load or when new objects are added to the collection but NOT if the setter is invoked from the UI (i.e. the getter does get called if I write some code to set the property).  For a number of reasons I'm forced to use VS2008 for this project so I'm using .NET 3.5

Comment: @Blam - that's exacly what this problem looks like.  It seems that the UI is thinking that because it is calling the setter that it should then ignore any notifications generated as a result of that.  On the face of it this seems sensible (to avoid potential infinite notification loops) but if this is the case it'd be nice to override this behaviour

Comment: @youpTube, passing null has no effect...

Comment: Like I said .NET 4.5  fixed it for me.  What version are you on?  No is is not sensible for the UI to not honor a get if I call INPC.  If  don't want the UI involved then I will not call INPC.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but _DeviceID has to be a public property and implement PropertyChanged inorder to get the UI to reflect any changes made to it.

So change the property to

```
private int _DeviceID;
public int DeviceID
    {
        get
        {

          return _DeviceID;

        }

        set
        {
          _DeviceID = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("DeviceID");
        }
```

Comment: Krishna, this is what I have.  The underlying data type (_DeviceID) is a private in and the property (DeviceID) is publicly exposed.  In my case though I'm exposing DeviceID as a string (and do the relevant casing).  Just for kicks I did change my code over to expose the property as an int and there was no difference in behaviour.  Unfortunately this is not the solution :(